# Masking a value in a column of a pandas dataframe and setting a flag in the same row (but different column)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, imputation

The problem:

I would like to impute missing values and set a flag in another column that the value is imputed - if that value itself is not missing.

Masking would do a great job with replacing the missing values but I don't know how to simultaneously set up also a flag in a different column.

Here is an example of a dataframe containing missing values and of a series that contains imputed values that can be used to replace the missing values - however the series itself contains some missing values.

```
df_orig = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'period': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'volume': [1, 2, np.NaN, 4, 5, 6, 7, np.NaN, 9, np.NaN, 11, np.NaN],
                   'is_imputed': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

imputed_vol = pd.Series([np.NaN, np.NaN, 3, 4, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN])
```

In the above case only the missing value in the 3rd row in "volume" can be replaced by an imputed value. So the end result would be:

```
df_orig = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'period': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'volume': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, np.NaN, 9, np.NaN, 11, np.NaN],
                   'is_imputed': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

I can easily do the replacing by masking

```
df_orig.mask(df_orig.volume.isna(), imputed_vol, axis=0)
```

but how do I set up also the flag 'is_imputed'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and boolean arithmetic:

```
# keep copy of original column
original = df_orig['volume']

# fill value
df_orig['volume'] = df_orig['volume'].fillna(imputed_vol)

# check if value has changed
df_orig['is_imputed'] = (df_orig['volume'].ne(original)
                         & imputed_vol.notna() # required as NaN != NaN
                         ).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    cust_id  period  volume  is_imputed
0         1       1     1.0           0
1         1       2     2.0           0
2         1       3     3.0           1
3         1       4     4.0           0
4         1       5     5.0           0
5         1       6     6.0           0
6         2       1     7.0           0
7         2       2     NaN           0
8         2       3     9.0           0
9         2       4     NaN           0
10        2       5    11.0           0
11        2       6     NaN           0
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help over the last few days. I struggle to find answers to a question so I put a bounty on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748716/line-plot-for-time-series-of-grouped-data-in-pandas/76748762#76748762. Can you, perhaps, help once more?

Answer (score 1):

With simple boolean clause (without temporary reference):

```
df_orig['is_imputed'] = (imputed_vol.notna() & df_orig['volume'].isna()).astype(int)
df_orig['volume'] = df_orig['volume'].fillna(imputed_vol)
```

---

```
    cust_id  period  volume  is_imputed
0         1       1     1.0           0
1         1       2     2.0           0
2         1       3     3.0           1
3         1       4     4.0           0
4         1       5     5.0           0
5         1       6     6.0           0
6         2       1     7.0           0
7         2       2     NaN           0
8         2       3     9.0           0
9         2       4     NaN           0
10        2       5    11.0           0
11        2       6     NaN           0
```